# ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 even though the execution was successful

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm running an asp.net 2.0 web application. Suddenly this morning, ExecuteNonQuery started returning -1, even though the commands in the SP that ExecuteNonQuery is running, are executing (I see items inserted and updated in the DB), and there is no exception thrown.

This happens only when I am connected to our production DB. When I'm connected to our development DB they return the  correct number of rows affected.

Also, interestingly enough, ExecuteDataSet doesn't have problems - it returns DataSets beautifully.

So it doesn't seem like a connection problem. But then, what else could it be?

Comment: I remember it coz a friend of mine had spent a whole night tracking that bug :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also check the procedure to see if there's this line of code in there -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

This will cause the ExecuteNonQuery to always return -1.

Comment: The problem was indeed NOCOUNT being on, but not in the SP level, but in the Database Server level. It was accidentally set when our DBA ran the following command:

declare @option int

set @option = @@options | 64

exec sp_configure 'user options', @option

RECONFIGURE

And the way to undo it is: In SQL Management Studio, right click the relevant Database Engine, and choose Properties. Then choose "connections" from the "Select a Page" list. There, under "Default connection options", un-check the checkbox near "no count"

Answer (score 2):

-1 means "No rows effected".
SELECT statement will also return -1.

Check the effect of the SP on dev and live environments.

Taken from [SqlCommand::ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery - Does "return value includes the number of rows affected by both" that the sum of numbers of affected rows is returned?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter [almost same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563865/why-this-npgsqldataadapter-update-command-always-return-1) (in Postgresql though) with NpgsqlDataAdapter, the Update method always returns 1.

Perhaps your connection string to your development db is different from your production db.  Or if there's really no difference between their connection strings, perhaps your production db's service pack is different from your development db.

Answer (score 0):

ExceuteNonQuery returns -1 for all types stored procedure as per the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx#See%20Also)

it will returns updated records values only in case of sattment